# C#|Working with process help

Tags: c#, asp.net

a few days ago i started working with process, i did a few things.. and wanted to ask a question.

lets say i got a process :

```
process = Process.Start("D:\\Server1\\orangebox\\srcds.exe", "srcds.exe -console -game cstrike  +maxplayers 16 -port 27017 +map de_dust2");
            process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

            process.Exited += new EventHandler(process_Exited);
        }

        void process_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            process = Process.Start("D:\\Server1\\orangebox\\srcds.exe", "srcds.exe -console -game cstrike  +maxplayers 16 -port 27017 +map de_dust2");
            process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

            process.Exited += new EventHandler(process_Exited);
```

so, its works perfect. but, how can i do new process? but. added them from a button and the info of them comes from a textbox.

lets say i got `button1` and 3 `textbox`. 1 of the `textboxs` give me the process name, 1 the args, and 1 if to run now ot not.

so how can i do that?

thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ProcessStartInfo class to specify an arguments and assign it to relative property of your Process class.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo(v=vs.71).aspx

If you don't want process run now, initialize it but don't call Run() NOW.

Comment: i tryied to do this : process = Process.Start("D:\\Server1\\orangebox\\srcds.exe", "srcds.exe -console -game cstrike  +maxplayers 16 -port 27017 +map de_dust2");
            process = Process.Start("C:\\Servers\\Servers\\css-1\\orangebox\\srcds.exe", "srcds.exe -console -game cstrike  +maxplayers 16 -port 27017 +map de_dust2"); but the, when i close one of them, the close button wont work any one, can i get "id" of a procces?

Comment: Process has an ID property. But It's not clear to me what you're going to aachieve. What is that "close" button ? Is it window's standart close button or you have somewhere Close button that have ti do something? To get the right answer be more precise in your problem description.

Comment: i mean, can i run some more process on the same process. i mean : doing process1 Process, and them process1 = process.start() and then do more process.starts, and then close servers by id?